# Difference between these two R functions

Tags: r

I am trying to illustrate the three types of extreme value distributions in R.

For type one, the distribution function is as follows.

[image]

In R I wrote the following lines.

```
G1 <- function(z, a, b){
  x = (b-z)/a
  y = exp(-exp(x))
  y
}

G1(-3:3, 2, 3)
```

And I got what I intended, i.e., a finite sequence of numbers.

```
 [1] 1.89e-09 5.12e-06 6.18e-04 1.13e-02 6.60e-02 1.92e-01 3.68e-01
```

For type two, the distribution function is as follows.

[image]

In R I wrote the following lines.

```
G2 <- function(z, a, b, alpha){
  if(z<b||z==b){
    0
  } else {
    x = -((z-b)/a)^{-alpha}
    y = exp(x)
    y
  }
}

G2(-3:3, 2, 3, 4)
```

***However, this time I only got one number.***

```
[1] 0
```

Where did I make a mistake in writing the second function G2, please? I want to have a finite sequence instead of just one number. Thank you!

Comment: The second is not vectorized. You could rewrite it to be, or just use `G2 <- Vectorize(function ...))`

Comment: @rawr Vectorize is so cool. Thanks. How to rewrite the function without using Vectorize, please? I mean in a simple way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `||` operator only looks at the first element of `z<b` and `z==b`.  This should work:

```
G2 <- function(z, a, b, alpha)
    ifelse(z<=b, 0,exp(-((z-b)/a)^(-alpha)))
```